# Html5 audio recording not working on iphone

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-safari

Does html5 audio recording is supported on iPhone. I have written code but it is not working.
Is there any thing wrong with the code

```
 <h2>capture=microphone</h2>
 <input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone"></input>
 <h2>Test 2</h2>
 <input type="file" accept="audio/*" id="capture" />
```

It is working fine on Android 2.1
If iPhone do not support html5 audio recording, what is the best alternative way to implement it?

Comment: Wow, did not know you could do that on an Android phone. Will have to test that out sometime.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will currently only work on Android 3.0 devices, you could however look at
using phone gap and their javascript media apis

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#CaptureAudioOptions